# Интеграция appsflyer SDK

Tags: java, android

Всем доброго дня, с Android разработкой только знакомлюсь, прошу не кидать камни. Решил в свое приложение интегрировать AppsFlyer SDK для дальнейшего отслеживания трафика, делал все по инструкции, но при попытке компилирования приложение запускается, но сразу же вылетает. Не подскажите куда смотреть, чтобы исправить данную проблему. Заранее спасибо.

[Документация по SDK](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/ru/articles/207032126-%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-Android-SDK-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2#%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-22-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-android-%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E)

Мой код:

build.gradle

```
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.9'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin:  'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: 'ad7d98b3-c263-4065-a891-bd884fb6753a',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
        applicationId "com.example.quizshow"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.4'
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:5.4.5'
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:5.4.5'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static String AF_DEV_KEY = "xULabDxxCwdQhvLXMM3DZF";
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AppsFlyerConversionListener conversionListener = new AppsFlyerConversionListener() {


            @Override
            public void onConversionDataSuccess(Map<String, Object> conversionData) {

                for (String attrName : conversionData.keySet()) {
                    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "attribute: " + attrName + " = " + conversionData.get(attrName));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConversionDataFail(String errorMessage) {
                Log.d("LOG_TAG", "error getting conversion data: " + errorMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAppOpenAttribution(Map<String, String> attributionData) {

                for (String attrName : attributionData.keySet()) {
                    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "attribute: " + attrName + " = " + attributionData.get(attrName));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onAttributionFailure(String errorMessage) {
                Log.d("LOG_TAG", "error onAttributionFailure : " + errorMessage);
            }
        };

        AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().init(AF_DEV_KEY, conversionListener, this);

        // Logging set to help debug issues, remove before releasing your app.
        OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);
        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1; Mi A1 Build/N2G47H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36");
        this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                    view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                    return true;
                }
            };
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().startTracking(this);
        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.quizshow">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <!-- Optional : -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.example.quizshow.MainActivity"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.QuizShow">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver android:name="com.appsflyer.SingleInstallBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

В манифесте с <application до  все подсвечивается желтым.

---

лог ошибок

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.quizshow, PID: 6170
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.quizshow.MainActivity: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.quizshow.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Application
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1244)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6683)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.quizshow.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Application
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1158)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6683) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Смотреть надо в первую очередь в логи - там будет сообщение об ошибке и указание на проблемную строку в коде. Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. Также надо заметить, что если вы действительно собираетесь сделать приложение с открытием YouTube в WebView, то вам не получится его выложить в GooglePlay - сразу забанят, т.к. у вас, по идее, нет разрешения от гугла на подобное использование. Тем паче, что есть либа для Yuotube, а WebView приложения почти полностью и сами по себе запрещены.

Comment: Да ютуб я просто так вставил как пример, естественно там другой сайт будет.Лог ошибок ниже отправил

Comment: Попробуйте удалить строку `android:name="com.example.quizshow.MainActivity"` из application тэга манифеста

Comment: спасибо,заработало!

Comment: Не спешите радоваться) Вы не вполне точно следовали документации. Вы инициализируете SDK в Activity, а надо, согласно доке, в Application. Перечитайте ещё раз доку. Вам надо создать класс-наследник `Application` и именно в нём все действия с SDK делать. Потом этот класс прописать в манифесте вместо удалённой вами строки. То как сейчас у вас - работать, возможно, будет при соблюдении ряда условий, но вот точность работы не будет гарантирована, т.к. активити может быть пересоздана при повороте экрана, например, что приведёт к неизвестным результатам